# Failed to "import gurobipy" after running setup.py or pysetup.bat

Tags: python, gurobi

After typing "import gurobipy", this would show up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gurobipy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .gurobipy import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing gurobipy: 找不到指定的模块。(EN:The specified module could not be found)
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python and gurobi, and made sure both are the 64 bits version.

Comment: Can you share how you installed Gurobi? Were there any error messages or warnings?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new Windows safety feature that [changes how DLLs are loaded in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#ctypes) and that affects the installation of Gurobi.
You need to tell Python how to find the library again. This can be done either by

- copying the `gurobi90.dll` from `gurobi901\win64\bin\` to `PYTHON_INSTALLATION_PATH\lib\site-packages\gurobipy\` or by
- specifying how the library can be found within the current Python environment:

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory(os.path.join(os.getenv('GUROBI_HOME'), 'bin'))
```

The Anaconda Python distribution is not affected by this change and the installation works as intended.

**note:** This is only affecting Gurobi 9.0.1.